# I have a suggestion for a tag merge

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

It seems to me that the [book-management](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-management) tag should be merged with the [ebook-management](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebook-management) one.

Since the whole site is about ebooks, it seems implicit to me that every question labelled as such is really about ebooks and not physical, paper books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes perfect sense to me. I have done the merge.

Comment: Agreed; thanks.

Comment: @EdCottrell: I'm glad you agree. I jumped the gun and made the change hoping you and Nathan had the same point of view on this one.